# how to resolve google sheets API error with python

Tags: python, google-sheets, google-sheets-api

I am trying to read / write to google sheets using python.

I run this boilerplate code, but get the following error:

```
APIError: {'code': 403, 'message': 'Request had insufficient authentication scopes.', 'errors': [{'message': 'Insufficient Permission', 'domain': 'global', 'reason': 'insufficientPermissions'}], 'status': 'PERMISSION_DENIED', 'details': [{'@type': 'type.googleapis.com/google.rpc.ErrorInfo', 'reason': 'ACCESS_TOKEN_SCOPE_INSUFFICIENT', 'domain': 'googleapis.com', 'metadata': {'method': 'google.apps.drive.v3.DriveFiles.List', 'service': 'drive.googleapis.com'}}]}
```

what i have done:

- I have followed the instructions and setup the google-API key.
- i have downloaded the json key (named it `google_keys.json`).
- i created a new google sheet called `test sheet` for testing.

```py
import gspread
from google.oauth2.service_account import Credentials


# Use the credentials to create a client to interact with the Google Drive API
scopes = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']
creds = Credentials.from_service_account_file('google_keys.json', scopes=scopes)

client = gspread.authorize(creds)

# Open a sheet from a spreadsheet in Google Sheets
sheet = client.open("test sheet").worksheet("Sheet1")

# Read a range of cells
cell_list = sheet.range('A1:C7')

# Print the values in the range of cells
for cell in cell_list:
    print(cell.value)

# Write values to the sheet
sheet.update_acell('B2', "I am writing to B2")
```

It appears to be an authentication problem.
So my question is, what else to i need to do to get this test code working ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The message says that the request has insufficient scopes, and points out that the method `google.apps.drive.v3.DriveFiles.List` is the one that triggered the error. This means that you need to add a Drive scope so the script can read your files, probably to search for a spreadsheet with the specified filename.

From the gspread [documentation](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.7.0/oauth2.html), these are the scopes that you need to authenticate with a service account:

```
scopes = [
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets',
    'https://www.googleapis.com/auth/drive'
]
```

Note that you also need to share your spreadsheet with the service account that you got the `google_keys.json` file from. It ends in `...gserviceaccount.com`. Make sure that you generated the [right keys](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys).

##### Reference:

- [gspread Authentication](https://docs.gspread.org/en/v5.7.0/oauth2.html)
- [Managing service account keys](https://cloud.google.com/iam/docs/creating-managing-service-account-keys)

Comment: works, this is an excellent, well explained, answer.  Thanks.

Comment: i also had to enable the Google Drive API.